# How can I scan foreign characters (like ä, ß, ő, ű) and print them out to the console window as well?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, getline

Here is my simplified code. I would like to scan the characters typed in by the user and print them in the following line. Obviously there are some problems arising with non-English characters. In the program I should use German letters like ä, ö, ü and ß, plus some others as well (á, ë, é, í, ő, ű).

I have tried to fix the problem in many ways. I tried to insert the line

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "German");
```

so that at least the German characters be scanned and printed. It didn't work at all: it seems getline for some reason doesn't take in the characters typed in.

Then I substituted getline with

```
std::wcin >> myString;
```

But this didn't do much either. After typing in äëßö, I obtained this: "÷á<.

The funny thing is that without setlocale, getline seems to work well and precisely gives back the characters I typed in. However, std::wcout doesn't display well the following: "Solution (with äëáéíöüőűß): ". Then, as soon as I write in the setlocale line, getline goes crazy but "Solution (with äëáéíöüőűß): " is now printed correctly.

How should I modify the code to meet these expectations?
I use Windows platform if that might have an importance.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    int iii = 1;
    do
    {
        std::wcout << "Type in a string (with äëáéíöüőűß) : " << endl;
        wstring myString;
        getline(std::wcin, myString);
        std::wcout << "Solution (with äëáéíöüőűß): " << myString << endl;

    } while (iii < 50);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not c, please choose the tags carefuly if you want to recieve an answer.

Comment: Which code set are you configured to use — 8859-15 or UTF-8 or something else?  I see you're on Windows; the `_tmain()` means Windows, not Unix.

Comment: Also, what platform?  Windows?  OS X?  Unix?  And what console or shell? Much of this is platform-specific.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, if I'm not mistaken it's  8859-16. But not 100% sure, I'm yet only a beginner in computer programming. :/

Comment: I don't know enough about Windows programming to have much help to offer.  Nevertheless, those who do know probably need the information.  Are you sure the locale should be German and not something like `de_DE`?  If you're using an 8859-x code set (-15 or -16), then it is a single byte code set and you don't need to use the wide-character I/O.  I don't know what happens when you do use wide character, though.  Ideally, it would all just 'work', but apparently, it doesn't.  I don't think I can offer any extra help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I checked my answer with "de_DE" and it did not work. It did work with "German".

Comment: OK; go with what works.  Like I said, I don't know what's correct (but I'm mildly appalled — though not very surprised — that you have to type "German" rather than say "Deutsch"; it seems horribly Anglo-centric to make people from Germany type the English name of their country).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do any input or output, you must set the modes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    ::std::locale d_Locale2( "German" );
    ::std::locale::global( d_Locale2 );
    _setmode( _fileno( stdin ), _O_U16TEXT );
    _setmode( _fileno( stderr ), _O_U16TEXT );
    _setmode( _fileno( stderr ), _O_U16TEXT );

    ::std::wcout << L"Type in a string (with äëáéíöüőűß) : " << ::std::endl;
    ::std::wstring myString;
    ::std::getline( ::std::wcin, myString );
    ::std::wcout << L"Solution (with äëáéíöüőűß): " << myString << ::std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean just copying this before int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) ? Because that'll drop a dozen of errors.
I'm sorry if I ask nonsense, I'm yet new to C++ and computer programming as a whole.

Comment: @lazarea: I noticed now that you are new to SO. Welcome. I improved my answer to make it executable. I tested using Windows 8.1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, @Hector! :)